# Extend Wordpress search with category dropdown

Tags: php, css, wordpress, search

I'm trying to extend the Wordpress search with a category dropdown.

This is what I have so far:

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
    <input type="text" class="search-field" name="s" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Heb je een vraag? Vraag maar raak!', 'mytimo' ) ?>" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
    <?php
    $swp_cat_dropdown_args = array(
            'show_option_all'   => __( 'Alle categorieën', 'mytimo' ),
            'name'              => 'swp_category_limiter',
            'hide_empty'        => 1,
            'hierarchical'       => 1,
            'child_of'           => 0,
        );
    wp_dropdown_categories( $swp_cat_dropdown_args );
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="artikels" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Zoeken', 'mytimo' ); ?>">
</form>
```

The search works, but all the articles are shown with that searchterm, not only the articles with the searchterm + the chosen category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your dropdown Args like this:

```
$swp_cat_dropdown_args = array(
        'show_option_all'   => __( 'Alle categorieën', 'mytimo' ),
        'name'              => 'cat', // here change swp_category_limiter to cat
        'hide_empty'        => 1,
        'hierarchical'       => 1,
        'child_of'           => 0,
    );
```

Comment: I didn't think it was so ease, if I look at the answer I realise that I should've seen it myself. Thanks!